# Expression for $1 - 2^z x + 3^z x^2 - 4^z x^3 + \cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series, taylor-expansion

Using Taylor series we have

$$\frac 1 {(1+x)^2} = 1 - 2x + 3x^2 - 4x^3 + \cdots$$

Then multiplying by $x$ and differentiating we get

$$\frac {1-x} {(1+x)^3} = 1 - 4 x + 9 x^2  - 16 x^3 + \cdots$$

Continuing like this we can find an expression for

$$1 - 2^n x + 3^n x^2 - 4^n x^3 + \cdots$$

where $n$ is an integer. The denominator is as expected $(1+x)^{n+1}$ and the numerator is an $n-1$ degree polynomial whose coefficients satisfy a simple recurrence relation.

I am having trouble finding anything for when $n$ is a real (or complex) number though. Is there a nice expression for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), $\mathrm{Li}_{-z}(-x)$

Comment: Well that was easy, hadn't heard of it :) thanks!